# Can a listener method run when activity is dead?

Tags: android

please help, I am using Firebase for the backend of my app, developing the app on Android Studio. I am writing data to Firebase like this

```
FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection(Constants.DRIVER_USERS_COLLECTION)
                                        .document(AppData.getInstance().getDriverNumber())
                                        .update(Constants.RATINGS, FieldValue.arrayUnion(rating))
                                        .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                                            @Override
                                            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {

                                                if (task.isSuccessful())
                                                    Log.i(Constants.TAG, "ratings added to driver doc");
                                                else Log.i(Constants.TAG, "failed to add ratings to driver doc");

                                            }
                                        });
```

but just after that I also finish the current activity like this

```
startActivity(new Intent(this, HomeActivity.class));
finish();
```

Now here's what I would like to know, if the onCompleteListener is triggered after the activity is dead, will this piece of code still run?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In theory yes.
In practice, you can test it easily.

write inside the oncomplete listener :

```
if(isFinishing()){
    throw new RuntimeException("I was called from inside the listener");
}
```

and of course have the activity dead by the time the listener should return

Comment: Thanks, I needed a way to test it, and your solution is perfect